# What is 'n-dynamics' mentioned by Poli?

Tags: dynamic-systems

In a [seminar abstract titled "THE UNREASONABLE INEFFECTIVENESS OF MATHEMATICS IN COGNITIVE SCIENCES"](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/seminar/poli.txt) by Roberto Poli, he mentions

> I will consider some conceptual issues that might prove important for
>   framing the problem of cognitive mathematics (= mathematics for the
>   cognitive sciences), namely **the problem of n-dynamics**, of identity, of
>   timing, and of the specious present.

What is **n-dynamics**?

Comment: The link provides an email address - to me it looks like a self-invented term. If the author is still around, you may shoot him an email. I googled around a bit using the appropriate keywords, but nothing shows up. It looks like an isolated use of the word. You would likely have to read the full paper to understand it and at least I can't access it.

Comment: As a guess, I would assume he means "n-dimensional dynamics".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted the author. He's now in University of Trento.

He says it refers to the theory of multiple levels of reality, the dynamics of each level, and the interaction among them.

Comment: Please feel free to accept your own answer.